# Why does this c++ syntax with WINAPI mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, syntax

`BOOL (WINAPI *ZTSQueryUserToken)(ULONG SessionId, PHANDLE phToken) = NULL;`

To me it looks like a variable being created for a struct or something but I've never seen this type of syntax so can someone break it down for me?

Comment: It's a function pointer with a calling convention. See the spiral rule.

Comment: So you can use this function pointer with any function that has those two parameters? I'm failing to see what the WINAPI part has to do with this.

Comment: It is the calling convention, __stdcall.

Comment: @BrianTHannan: The usefulness is greatest for functions that aren't available on all Windows versions.  Instead of your program not even loading (the default behavior) or crashing later, when it tries to call the function (you get this with delay loading), if you use function pointers and `GetProcAddress`, you can find out the function doesn't exist and do something else instead of calling it (disable a feature, or use an workaround)

Comment: The utility [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) is very helpful in decoding complex C declarations.  Unfortunately, it struggles here, since it can't handle `BOOL`, calling conventions, or parameter names for function pointer arguments; the closest working example I could make was [this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*ZTSQueryUserToken%29%28ULONG%2C+PHANDLE%29).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WINAPI convention is usually used to call Win32 API functions. 
WINAPI is simply `__stdcall`

`#define WINAPI __stdcall`

The `__stdcall` calling convention has following characteristics in general:

- Passing arguments from right to left, and placed on the stack.
- Cleanup  of Stack is performed by the calling function.
- The function name has an underscore character and appending a '@' character and the number of bytes of stack space required.

So leaving behind `__stdcall`, use the ["Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to get

```
            +----------------------+
            |   +----------------+ |
            |   |                | |
            |   ^                | |
BOOL (WINAPI* ZTSQueryUserToken  ) ( ULONG SessionId, PHANDLE phToken) 
 ^          ^                    | |
 |          +--------------------+ |
 +---------------------------------+
```

Thus, Identifier :

- `ZTSQueryUserToken` is a
- pointer to a (`__stdcall`) function having arguments of types `ULONG` and `PHANDLE`
- returning `BOOL`

And the pointer is assigned to `NULL` in your case.

Comment: What a fantastically complete response! It has been a while on StackOverflow since I've received as well-composed an answer as this. I really do sincerely thank you for this.